# Undefined variable in returning foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

i want to write file scan script

this script must search in lot's of folders and make list from files

i wrote this script , but return not working

```
function checkdir($dir) {
    $file_array = array();
   if (is_dir($dir)) {
     $objects = scandir($dir);
     foreach ($objects as $key => $object) {
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") {
             // folder loop , try find files again
             checkdir($dir."/".$object);
             //$file_array[] = 'dir';

         } else {
             $file_array[] = $dir."/".$object;
             //echo $dir."/".$object.'<br>';
         }
       }

     }// end foreach
     //reset($objects);
   }
     return $file_array;

}
```

as you can see in `else` condition i wrote `$file_array[] = $dir."/".$object;` it's printing value but can not store value into array

Comment: Why don't you use the DirectoryIterator? http://php.net/manual/de/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: you never store the return value of `checkdir()` recursive calls, so this function will only ever return the contents of the top-level director you pass in. Everything else is basically useless, since you iterate all the sub-directories then throw away the results.

Comment: @MarcB sorry , i can't understand your means , can you post example of this ? i want to return array in this function

Comment: you need `$results[] = checkdir(...);`-type stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive call needs to add its results into the array:

```
$file_array = array_merge($file_array, checkdir($dir."/".$object));
```

Whole function:

```
function checkdir($dir) {
    $file_array = array();
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $key => $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") {
                    // folder loop , try find files again
                    $file_array = array_merge($file_array, checkdir($dir."/".$object));
                    //$file_array[] = 'dir';
                } else {
                    $file_array[] = $dir."/".$object;
                    //echo $dir."/".$object.'<br>';
                }
            }
        }// end foreach
    //reset($objects);
    }
    return $file_array;
}
```

Comment: i've changed it but still not woking

Comment: Maybe you didn't change it correctly, I've posted the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

How about that :

```
if ( ! function_exists('glob_recursive')){
    // Does not support flag GLOB_BRACE

    function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0){
        $files = glob($pattern, $flags);

        foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir){
            $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
        }

        return $files;
    }
}

?>
```

This is an exemple from php.net, check "glob".